# How can I get a javascript function in snowflake to return one value if the argument is numeric or another value if the argument is not numeric?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My company is transitioning from an oracle database solution to snowflake data warehouse. I am converting our user defined oracle functions to snowflake user defined functions. One function we have in oracle will return a 1 if the passed value is numeric, and a 0 if the passed value is non-numeric.

To be more specific, I want to update a column (x_value) when the value column has a numeric value in it. For instance, if I have a field titled creditscore with values of 700, 599, 'no record' in rows, I need to update a field (xscore) with the numeric values and leave the non-numeric creditscore null in the xscore field.

I am new to javascript (well, not new exactly -- I did work with it all day today), and have had no luck. Here is the basic function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnum(x variant)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE javascript
'
IF (isNan(x))
{
RETURN 1;
}
ELSE RETURN 0;
';
```

I have also tried typeof but get the same error, shown below:

```
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected ''

IF (isNan(x))
{
RETURN 1;
}
ELSE RETURN 0;

''.
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a user defined function for this. You can use Snowflake's TRY_TO_NUMBER function.

```
create or replace table TEST1 (s string);

insert into TEST1 select ('Not a number');
insert into TEST1 select ('750');

select try_to_number(s) from TEST_IS_NUMBER;
```

Then you can insert from this select.

Comment: Thank you. I am sure that is a better approach than the one I was taking. So, here is what I have tried and the results. I would like to update a table with the score if it is a numeric value (the data I get sometimes comes with string values instead of numeric values). Here is what I tried 
`UPDATE score SET score_num = raw_score WHERE to_variant(raw_score) = TRUE; '. 
It runs but gets 0 rows updated (should be 7,277). From the snowflake documentation the IS_REAL function returns TRUE. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried `UPDATE score SET score_num = raw_score (SELECT iff(is_real(raw_score), raw_score ::integer, NULL));' but get SQL Error [1044] [42P13]: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 61
Invalid argument types for function 'IS_REAL': (VARCHAR(255))' error message.

Comment: `select try_to_number(real_score);`

Comment: Hi Jerry, I edited my code snippet to reflect that the raw_score is originally a varchar. The IS_REAL function as waldente alludes works for variants but not for varchars. Let us know if that worked.

Answer (score 2):

If it is Javascript then it is case sensitive.

```
if ( isNaN(x) ) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

Or you could always use a ternary operator:

```
return ( isNaN(x) ? 1 : 0 );
```

However, I have never used Snowflake before, so if it requires the JS to be formatted in a specific manner than I am unable to help with that (just the vanilla JS syntax itself).

Comment: One more thing -- in Snowflake make X uppercase in the JavaScript body.  That's because it's outside the body.